# I want to make place to collect all path of folder

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, path, google-colaboratory

This is my code.

```
folder_out = []
for a in range(1,80): 
    folder_letter = "/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/"
    folder_out[a] = os.path.join(folder_letter, str(a))
    folder_out.append(folder_out[a])
```

and this is an error
[image]

and this what I want
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the os method wrong, you want to use os.listdir(Your directory here) to get a list of all directories

```
import os

dir = os.listdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/")
for f in dir:
    print(f)
```

If you just want a list of all directories, just use `os.listdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/")`

Comment: If I want to make directorie as a variable in array name "folder_out". What should I do?

Comment: The variable "dir" is the same as the variable you want called "folder_out"

Answer (score 0):

It's simply pointless to create a variable. They are unnecessary: You can store everything in lists, dictionaries and so on. Creating a new variables inside loop is very very bad practice.

Code correction: save in list instead and access them using loops or slicing.

```
import os
folder_out = []

for a in range(1,80): 
    folder_letter = "/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/"
    folder= os.path.join(folder_letter, str(a))
    folder_out.append(folder)

print(folder_out)
```

Gives list of folder names.

```
['/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/1', '/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/2', '/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/3', '/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/4', '/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/5', '/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/6', '/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/7', '/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/8', '/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/9',.....]
```

If you want to iterate over them.

```
for elment in folder_out:
    print(elment)
```

Which gives #

```
element 1
elem2nt 2...
```

Like

```
for x in folder_out:
    print(f"folder_out{c}: {x}")
    c= c+1
```

Gives what you want

```
folder_out0: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/1
folder_out1: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/2
folder_out2: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/3
folder_out3: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/4
folder_out4: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/5
folder_out5: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/6
folder_out6: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/7
folder_out7: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/8
folder_out8: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/9
folder_out9: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/10
folder_out10: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/11
folder_out11: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/12
folder_out12: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/13
folder_out13: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/14
folder_out14: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/15
folder_out15: /content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/data/16
```

If you want to create a folder for each path:

```
import os
for x in folder_out:

    os.mkdir(x)
```

which will create 79 empty folders